# Class does not conform protocol swift

Tags: class, swift, protocols

i have this error :

**Type 'CategoryTableViewController' does not conform to protocol 'XMLParserDelegateCategory'**

in this code:

class CategoryTableViewController: UITableViewController, XMLParserDelegateCategory {

```
var parser = CategoryParser(url: kURL)
var parsedItems: [CategorySchemes] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Navigation Mode"
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And my protocol is:

> protocol XMLParserDelegateCodelist {
>
> ```
> func XMLParserError(parser: CodeListParser, error: String) }
> ```
>
> class CodeListParser: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {
>
> ```
> let url: NSURL
> var delegate: XMLParserDelegateCodelist?
> ```

any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `func XMLParserError(parser: CodeListParser, error: String)` in your view controller.

Comment: i have implement :

parser.delegate = self

Comment: No, you tell the parser that your view controller conforms to the protocol but you do not implement the function the protocol declares. I.e. where is the code for the XMLParserError function?